# Django Rest Framework sending email but template doesnt load CSS

Tags: css, django, django-rest-framework, html-email

I am sending an email from Django Rest using django.core.mail module.

**Views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.utils.html import strip_tags
...



              ## Send the email somewhere in the viewset
            html_mail = render_to_string('templates/invitation.html', {'email': email, 'url': url})
            send_mail(
                'You are invited!',
                 mail_template,
                [sender_mail],
                [email],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
        
            return Response({'success' : 'true' },200)
```

I have template path in the **settings**,

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
   ],
```

And on the template I have the regular HTML template with a bunch of CSS code.

**Example Email Template:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no, date=no, address=no, email=no">
    <!--[if mso]>
    <xml><o:OfficeDocumentSettings><o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch></o:OfficeDocumentSettings></xml>
    <style>
      td,th,div,p,a,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;}
    </style>
  <![endif]-->
    <title>Default email title</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <style>
      .hover-underline:hover {
        text-decoration: underline !important;
      }

      @keyframes spin {
        to {
          transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
      }

      @keyframes ping {

        75%,
        100% {
          transform: scale(2);
          opacity: 0;
        }
      }

      @keyframes pulse {
        50% {
          opacity: .5;
        }
      }

      @keyframes bounce {

        0%,
        100% {
          transform: translateY(-25%);
          animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0, 1, 1);
        }

        50% {
          transform: none;
          animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
        }
      }

      @media (max-width: 600px) {
        .sm-leading-32 {
          line-height: 32px !important;
        }

        .sm-px-24 {
          padding-left: 24px !important;
          padding-right: 24px !important;
        }

        .sm-py-32 {
          padding-top: 32px !important;
          padding-bottom: 32px !important;
        }

        .sm-w-full {
          width: 100% !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; word-break: break-word; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; --bg-opacity: 1; background-color: #eceff1; background-color: rgba(236, 239, 241, var(--bg-opacity));">
    <div style="display: none;">Default email preheader</div>
    <div role="article" aria-roledescription="email" aria-label="Default email title" lang="en">
      <table style="font-family: Montserrat, -apple-system, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
        <tr>
          <td align="center" style="--bg-opacity: 1; background-color: #eceff1; background-color: rgba(236, 239, 241, var(--bg-opacity)); font-family: Montserrat, -apple-system, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;" bgcolor="rgba(236, 239, 241, var(--bg-opacity))">
            <table class="sm-w-full" style="font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial,sans-serif; width: 600px;" width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
              <tr>
                <td class="sm-py-32 sm-px-24" style="font-family: Montserrat, -apple-system, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; padding: 48px; text-align: center;" align="center">
                  <a href="https://1.envato.market/vuexy_admin">
                    <img src="images/logo.png" width="155" alt="Vuexy Admin" style="border: 0; max-width: 100%; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;">
                  </a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td align="center" class="sm-px-24" style="font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial,sans-serif;">
                  <table style="font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial,sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="sm-px-24" style="--bg-opacity: 1; background-color: #ffffff; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--bg-opacity)); border-radius: 4px; font-family: Montserrat, -apple-system, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; line-height: 24px; padding: 48px; text-align: left; --text-opacity: 1; color: #626262; color: rgba(98, 98, 98, var(--text-opacity));" bgcolor="rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--bg-opacity))" align="left">
                        <p style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 18px; margin-bottom: 0;">Hey</p>
                        <p style="font-weight: 700; font-size: 20px; margin-top: 0; --text-opacity: 1; color: #ff5850; color: rgba(255, 88, 80, var(--text-opacity));">John Doe!</p>
                        <p class="sm-leading-32" style="font-weight: 600; font-size: 20px; margin: 0 0 24px; --text-opacity: 1; color: #263238; color: rgba(38, 50, 56, var(--text-opacity));">
                           Best selling #1 admin template ever!
                        </p>
                        <a href="https://1.envato.market/vuexy_admin">
                          <img src="images/item.jpg" width="500" alt="Vuexy Admin" style="border: 0; max-width: 100%; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle;">
                        </a>
                        <p style="margin: 24px 0;">
                          <span style="font-weight: 600;">Vuexy</span>
                          is the most developer friendly & highly customisable VueJS + HTML Admin Dashboard Template
                          based on Vue CLI, Vuex & Vuexy component framework. 
                        </p>
                        <table style="font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial,sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation">
                          <tr>
                            <td style="font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial,sans-serif; padding-top: 32px; padding-bottom: 32px;">
                              <div style="--bg-opacity: 1; background-color: #eceff1; background-color: rgba(236, 239, 241, var(--bg-opacity)); height: 1px; line-height: 1px;">&zwnj;</div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                        <p style="margin: 0 0 16px;">
                          Not sure why you received this email? Please
                          <a href="mailto:support@example.com" class="hover-underline" style="--text-opacity: 1; color: #7367f0; color: rgba(115, 103, 240, var(--text-opacity)); text-decoration: none;">let us know</a>.
                        </p>
                        <p style="margin: 0 0 16px;">Thanks, <br>The PixInvent Team</p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial,sans-serif; height: 20px;" height="20"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: Montserrat, -apple-system, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif; font-size: 12px; padding-left: 48px; padding-right: 48px; --text-opacity: 1; color: #eceff1; color: rgba(236, 239, 241, var(--text-opacity));">
                        <p align="center" style="cursor: default; margin-bottom: 16px;">
                          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pixinvents" style="--text-opacity: 1; color: #263238; color: rgba(38, 50, 56, var(--text-opacity)); text-decoration: none;"><img src="images/facebook.png" width="17" alt="Facebook" style="border: 0; max-width: 100%; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 12px;"></a>
                          &bull;
                          <a href="https://twitter.com/pixinvents" style="--text-opacity: 1; color: #263238; color: rgba(38, 50, 56, var(--text-opacity)); text-decoration: none;"><img src="images/twitter.png" width="17" alt="Twitter" style="border: 0; max-width: 100%; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 12px;"></a>
                          &bull;
                          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/pixinvents" style="--text-opacity: 1; color: #263238; color: rgba(38, 50, 56, var(--text-opacity)); text-decoration: none;"><img src="images/instagram.png" width="17" alt="Instagram" style="border: 0; max-width: 100%; line-height: 100%; vertical-align: middle; margin-right: 12px;"></a>
                        </p>
                        <p style="--text-opacity: 1; color: #263238; color: rgba(38, 50, 56, var(--text-opacity));">
                          Use of our service and website is subject to our
                          <a href="https://pixinvent.com/" class="hover-underline" style="--text-opacity: 1; color: #7367f0; color: rgba(115, 103, 240, var(--text-opacity)); text-decoration: none;">Terms of Use</a> and
                          <a href="https://pixinvent.com/" class="hover-underline" style="--text-opacity: 1; color: #7367f0; color: rgba(115, 103, 240, var(--text-opacity)); text-decoration: none;">Privacy Policy</a>.
                        </p>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="font-family: 'Montserrat',Arial,sans-serif; height: 16px;" height="16"></td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**My Problem**

I send the email successfully (so finds the template) however I only send ugly structured texts.

If I don't do strip_tags in the views.py it sends template with the HTML tags.

I am sending an email for the first time, I searched it everywhere however nothing solved the problem. I am hoping there is an easy way since it is a very common action. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried testing your email in an environment that supports web fonts? https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/

Comment: It might help to show a screenshot of what you expect, versus a screenshot of what you get - and in what email environment that was (gmail on web? some app? apple mail? windows/android/iOS? versions?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is in here,

```
           send_mail(
                'You are invited!',
                 mail_template,
                [sender_mail],
                [email],
                fail_silently=False,
            )
```

Try changing it to

```
       send_mail(
                'You are invited!',
                 'random text here',
                [sender_mail],
                [email],
                fail_silently=False,
                html_message = render_to_string('emails/invitation.html', {'email': email, 'url': url})
                 ## So you specify the html_message parameter here. 
            )
```

Which was a solution to my problem.

Tip: You can use mailtrap to check which clients can or cannot support the content you send.

Comment: This is great, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
html_message = render_to_string(
    'templates/invitation.html', {'email': email, 'url': url})
email_from = settings.EMAIL_FROM
recipient_list = [email]
send_mail(subject=subject, message=None, from_email=email_from,
          recipient_list=recipient_list, html_message=html_message)
```